# Maven Java web project not recognised when importing into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, m2eclipse

A colleague is trying to import a Java web project project into his Eclipse workspace. He's installed the m2e plugin and it recognises the "parent" project and the 3 sub projects it has (which are also Maven projects). However when the projects are imported, Eclipse doesn't seem to recognise them as Java projects (it doesn't show the usual "Java Resources" and "Deployment Descriptor"). The only two things that appear in the Project Explorer are shown below:

[image: screenshot]

I've imported the same project using my version of Eclipse and it recognises that the project is a Java web project without any issues. Is there something he needs to do/install to get it to work? He has the Eclipse WTP as well as the m2e plugin, so I can't see any different between his Eclipse installation and mine.

Comment: as far as I know it is correct, as the main deployment descriptor would be inside src>main>webapp>web-inf

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah This is inside Eclipse's Project Explorer though, so there should be other items present such as "Deployed Resources" and "Javascript Resources" (among others)

Comment: How does your colleague import the project? It should be imported as an existing maven project (File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects).

Comment: Just like that. It's strange because it detects the projects without any issues, but after importing them it doesn't seem to recognise that they're Java projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, we needed to enable project facets in the project properties. I'm not sure why this wasn't enabled by default like it was when it was imported into my Eclipse installation, but enabling the appropriate project facets fixed the issues we were having.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [m2eclipse-wtp](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp) 0.15.x (from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/). It contains the necessary configurators to properly set the required project facets of Java EE projects, according to your pom.xml configuration.

Please note that m2eclipse-wtp is moving to the Eclipse foundation and is superceded by [m2e-wtp](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/). m2e-wtp 0.16.0 will be released on sept 28th 2012. Until then you can try playing with the latest [release candidate](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the project in the Package Explorer and performing Maven --> Update Project Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something like this once when I was using the "project explorer" view when I thought I was actually using the "package explorer" view. These two views will display your project differently.

Comment: Unfortunately both views produce the same result. I had a feeling this could be the cause too.